# ESC/POS Termal printer UTF-8 charset set up

Tags: android, utf-8, outputstream, thermal-printer, character-set

I am trying to print some currency with Citaq v8 (it has a termal printer), but it prints **?**, because of the printer character set.

I have byte array (UTF-8) data to print. But the printer has default some character set. How can I change the default character set programatically(like using byte array)? I need to change printer charset settings.

Device: Citaq v8 (the device has a termal printer)
PS: I could not find any developer docs.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps UTF-8 is not supported as a character set/code table.

Even EPSON is supported only on some models.
[FS ( C <Function 48>](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=337)

> Select character encode system
>
> ```
> ASCII   FS (  C  pL pH fn m
> Hex     1C 28 43 02 00 30 m
> Decimal 28 40 67  2  0 48 m
> ```
>
> TM-P20
>
> ```
> 1, 49  ASCII (ISCII)  ISCII: Indian Script Code for Information Interchange
> 2, 50  UTF-8          Unicode encoding system
> ```
>
> TM-m30II, TM-m30II-H, TM-m30II-NT
>
> ```
> 1, 49  1-byte character encoding  Non-Unicode encoding method (ASCII [extended], Shift JIS, Big5, GB2312, GB18030, KS C, etc.)
> 2, 50  UTF-8                      Unicode encoding system
> ```

---

You need to set the printer code page using the following two ESC/POS commands, and the character string to be requested for printing must be encoded and converted according to the code page before sending.

[ESC t](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32)

> Select character code table
>
> ```
> ASCII   ESC t   n
> Hex     1B  74  n
> Decimal 27  116 n
> ```

[ESC R](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=29)

> Select an international character set
>
> ```
> ASCII   ESC R   n
> Hex     1B  52  n
> Decimal 27  82  n
> ```

---

Alternatively, you can create all the page contents to be printed with a Bitmap image and print it with one of the ESC/POS commands related to image printing.
However, it will be slow.

Comment: I tried to setup the Epson TM-m30II with UTF-8 using the following code but it's still not printing Chinese characters

    28, 40, 67, 2, 0, 48, 2, 50

Comment: @Bhavesh Whether or not UTF-8 is supported may depend on the detailed branch model number of the target country, even if it is a model listed in the document, so please ask EPSON or your sales agent.