# How to print on thermal printer with cryllic letters? Android

Tags: bluetooth, thermal-printer

I couldn't print cryllic letter on thermal printer.

I'm using DantSu ESC/POS ANDROID library now, but I can't give a utf-8 charset in it, maybe someone used it before. please help me solve this problem or share a better library

GitHub link of library - https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android

Comment: Very few printers will support UTF-8. [ESC/POS Termal printer UTF-8 charset set up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63546719/9014308) In the description of the library, if you want to print a character from some country, find out what number the code table of that character is from the information on the code table supported by the printer you are using, and set the printer object to It says that you need to specify it when creating. [Charset encoding](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android#charset-encoding)

Answer (score -1):

one of solution you can try is to make pdf of the text you want to print, convert in base 64, convert in png or bmp, and then print it with the library.

For printing images with the library, you can use this tag

```
[C]<img>" + PrinterTextParserImg.bitmapToHexadecimalString(printer, myBitmap, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM))+"</img>\n
```